# Value isn't being added to sum if key is duplicate in array

Tags: postgresql

I have issue where SUM function is not actually calculating/adding values for duplicate key - it doesn't add to sum if there is same key in array twice, only once. I feel like it is skipping keys that appear more than once.

```
SELECT
    w.id,
    wc.name,
    wc.description,
    data_ids,                                     
    (SELECT SUM(d.length) FROM data d WHERE d.id = ANY(w.data_ids)) as length
FROM words w
LEFT JOIN "words_content" wc ON wc.word_id = w.id
WHERE 
w.id = 15
AND
wc.language_id = 2
```

So if I have length for data id `1, 2, 3` to be `1, 1, 4` and inside `data_ids` column i have `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3` it will display `length` 6 and not 12.

Is there a way to include it to keep adding to SUM even if the value of a key is already inside SUM? Note that `data_ids` is array of integers.

Comment: Read the docs [ANY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.30.16) * The result of ANY is “true” if any true result is obtained* `1,2,3` are found in the  beginning of  the array  so there is no need to go any further.

Comment: is it possible to somehow "cotinue" if true is returned and go further? @AdrianKlaver

Comment: No. What are you trying to achieve? I am not really following your example data and expected output.

Comment: i'm trying to add to ```SUM(d.length)``` for those ids that are duplicate - go thru whole array don't skip any ids (in this case duplicate ones). As you can see in example - current implementation return 6 instead of wanted 12 (12 is output if SUM(d.length) is added for duplicates too.) @AdrianKlaver

Comment: How about something like: `select sum(d) lateral from  unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]) as d; 12`?

Comment: but it changes for each this word. It's not the same for each one of them.

Comment: Again, you will  need to provide a better description of what you are trying to achieve. To your question add some example input data and expected output. Something more then the one record you have now.  Also the table definitions for `words` and `words_content`.